# Jenkins - Multiple terminal output

Tags: jenkins

I have a Python code that when running, creates multiple other terminal windows, in addition to the one I was already running from.

```
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "..."])
```

This opens multiple other terminals that runs the same program with different parameters.

In Jenkins, in a "Freestyle project", when I run the same script from the "Execute shell", the result is not the same (as I was expecting).

```
./python_file.py -p $MY_PARAMETER
```

The main console output is working fine, **but the other windows terminal that were supposed to open, just don't execute.** I want to be able to see the output of those terminals in the Jenkins console (or elsewhere ?)

Should I use another kind of project ? Or just add a new Plugin ? Is there an option in the project that I should checked ? I don't want to run the project on multiple nodes. I just need to see multiple terminals.

This is the error text :

```
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

It is not a common problem I supposed, but thanks for input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if a multiple windows output exists in Jenkins but I think that you can bypass this issue.

Instead of running **one** project in **multiple** console, I will modify my Python Script so that **multiple** projects will run **one** console at a time. Like that it will be easier to control which parameters I want to every single projects and what the outputs are for every single one of them also.

There is a couple way to do that ("multi-configuration project", multiple "freestyle project").